# How to upload files to google drive. Is it possible through Retrofit 2

Tags: android, file-upload, retrofit, retrofit2, google-drive-android-api

I have to upload some files to my google drive account. Currently I am using below code to upload the file to google drive

```
 OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
                        addTextfileToOutputStream(outputStream);
                        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                .setTitle("testFile")
                                .setMimeType("text/plain")
                                .setDescription("This is a text file uploaded from device")
                                .setStarred(true).build();
                        Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(googleApiClient)
                                .createFile(googleApiClient, changeSet, driveContents)
                                .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
```

Is there any method using Retrofit to upload a file. Any help should be greatly appreciated and helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

> How to upload files to google drive?

Here's the [Upload Quickstart for Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#uploads). Java sample is [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java#step_3_set_up_the_sample).

> Is it possible through Retrofit 2?

As long as you're able to make HTTP access, you can use Google Drive API. You'll be using java.net.URL class and the java.net.HttpURLConnection class. 
Here's a [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNetworking/article.html) with actual codes. Don't forget that to integrate the Drive platform, you need to [Setup it Up](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/enable-sdk#drive_integration) first.